WordPress current post functions inside loop doesn't work anymore, are they incompatible with php 8.0?
I recently update php from 7.4 to 8.0 , since many functions doesn't work anymore !
I don't know if it's related but I have tried many solutions and none of them works.
Using (get_...) , the_title, the_excerpt, the_content, etc inside new WP_Query and below conditions loop nothing are displayed .
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
      $the_query->the_post();
         var_dump(get_the_title());
   endwhile;
endif;

Strangely $post_id = get_the_id() and the_post_thumbnail() work !
If I use get_posts() : $postsA = get_posts($Activities)[0]; $postsA->post_title inside the loop I retrieve the title.
If I use get_the_title($post_id) or get_the_title() or the_title()  I have nothing. = NULL
My arguments :
$Activities = array(

    'post_type' => $activityType,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
                
        array(
            'key' => 'timestamps_between',
            'value' => array($firstdayweek_ts,$lastdaymidnight_ts),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )       
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $Activities );

My host charges for downgrading because it no longer guarantees stability.
I have tried with a simple loop (no argument) it's the same issue but get_the_id() return well the id of post.
if ( have_posts() ) : 
   while ( have_posts() ) : 
      the_post();
         var_dump(get_the_title());
   endwhile;
endif;

Do you have an idea where the problem come ?

There's no reason anything you've shared here would be incompatible with PHP 8.0+. Make sure WordPress itself is up to date and that your plugins are also compatible with PHP 8.

My problem comes from my internationalisation plugin which translates all the content of the article and the article's meta. I filtering all post functions as the_title, the_excerpt, etc. It uses the null argument in the function. PHP 8.0+ no longer allows the null argument. I will create another question for this problem.
